# External swf still loading to other scenes? How to properly unload?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have encountered same problem but in different scenario, i have 4 scenes and in my 4th scene i have 3 button inside that loads and unloads external swf. Within the 4th Scene it works perfectly but when i try to hit my main navigation (which links to Scene 1,2 and 3), the external swf is still loading to the other scenes... it's been crazy i've tried lots of method but it's not working.

Here is my script: Scene 4

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var Xpos:Number = 525;
var Ypos:Number = 200;
var swf:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader=new Loader();

var defaultSWF:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Steps/intro.swf");


loader.load(defaultSWF);
loader.x = Xpos;
loader.y = Ypos;
addChild(loader);
//button function 
function btnCLICK(event:MouseEvent):void{ removeChild(loader);
var newSWFRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Steps/" + event.target.name + ".swf");   
loader.load(newSWFRequest); loader.x = Xpos; loader.y = Ypos; //addChild(loader);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(){ 
loader.content.height = 140;
loader.content.scaleX = loader.content.scaleY;});
addChild(loader);

}

//button listeners
NewBusinessPermit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnCLICK);
RenewBusinessPermit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnCLICK);
RPTAPayment.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnCLICK);
```

And i put this script to all the other scenes (1,2,3) to unload the movies fron scene4

```
if(stage.contains(loader)){
removeChild(loader);
}
else{
loader = null;  // 've also tried replacing this with gotoAndPlay ("frame name");
}
```

**i actually wanted to state here that IT in these Scene (1,2 0r 3) there's still a trace of the external child swf that is still loading, remove it from the stage and continue to play whatever tween animations in this current scene. Else if you trace it that there's none, just continue and play tween animations in this current scene.

Well unfortunately i got errors, i dunno if my script meet the objective. HELP?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to unload your loaded swf :

```
loader.unloadAndStop( true ); 
if( stage.contains(loader) )    removeChild( loader );
loader = null;
```

you can see the doc [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop%28%29).

or you can try to stop all clips inside your loader too :

```
MovieClip(loader.content).stopAllMovieClips();
if( stage.contains(loader) )    removeChild( loader );
loader = null;
```

you can see the doc [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#stopAllMovieClips%28%29)

i think the first method should be good.

Comment: I've tried both scripts & I get this error: _italic_ TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at demo_fla::MainTimeline/frame130()[demo_fla.MainTimeline::frame130:2]

Comment: what is the code on this line ? is it on your loaded swf or your main swf ?

Comment: please debug your movie (ctrl+shift+enter) instead of running it (ctrl+enter), you will see better error information and the line where the error occurs. You can see the state of the variables too it's very usefull !

Comment: i can't use the 2nd script since every scenes has an automatic playing movieclips inside.  The error pops-up on every scenes (except on the scene holder of external swf). Each scenes has a coding for buttons.

Comment: OK that don't answer the question ;) but try to add the verification for the loader still exists: if( loader != null ){ loader. ... }; sure if you make null the loader variable and still try to access it, it will throw an error...

Comment: it conflicts with my navigation buttons that has Object roots:    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

btnHOME.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);
 function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void {
 Object(root).gotoAndPlay(129,"Homepage");
 
}
btnCITY.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, goProfile);
 function goProfile (e:MouseEvent):void {
 Object(root).gotoAndPlay(1,"CityProfile");
}
btnLOCAL.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, goLocal);
 function goLocal (e:MouseEvent):void {
 Object(root).gotoAndPlay(1,"LocalGovernment");
}... the error points out to Object(root) from the debugger

Comment: try trace your root object before accessing it to see if it exists and maybe add a if( root != null ){ use your root } this will avoid errors. i Never used root so i cannot help you much with this